# Non-blocking HTTP GET query on Android

Tags: android, http, get, nonblocking

I've heard that there might be a possibility to post GET query and pass it some handler in a way that doesn't make you wait for the answer: when answer comes, it just calls the given handler that handles the result.

This isn't about blocking UI, i know how to use AsyncTask. The problem is that i want to post 3-4 queries to the internet simultaniously.

Is there a way to do it in Android without creating too many threads?

Comment: how many threads is "too many"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [Apache commons HTTP core](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore-nio/index.html), which supports non-blocking IO (NIO). (and an [example](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore-nio/examples/org/apache/http/examples/nio/NHttpClient.java))